# Topological Markov Property and $D$-condition

Tags: probability, general-topology, dynamical-systems

I was reading two different articles and I came across these two definitions below:

$(1)$ A subshift $X \subseteq \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ has the topological Markov property (TMP) if for any finite subset $\Lambda$ of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ there exists a finite subset $\Lambda^{\prime}$ of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ with $\Lambda \subset \Lambda^{\prime}$ such that for any $x,y \in X$, if $x_{\Lambda^{\prime}\setminus \Lambda} = y_{\Lambda^{\prime}\setminus \Lambda}$, then $x_{\Lambda}y_{\Lambda^c} \in X$.

$(2)$ Given $\{T_n\}$ a Folner sequence for $\mathbb{Z}^d$, the pais $(X, \{T_n\})$ satisfies the $D$-condition if for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $T_n \subseteq \tilde{T}_n$ such that  $\frac{|\tilde{T}_n|}{|T_n|} \to 1$, and for all $x, y \in X$, there exists $z \in X$ such that $z_{T_n} = x_{T_n}$ and  $z_{\tilde{T}_n^c} = y_{\tilde{T}_n^c}$.

I was wondering what is the relation (and if there is, of course) between these definitions in the sense that one implies the other.

If  $\{T_n\}$ is a Folner sequence and $\Lambda$ is a finite set, we also have that $\{F_n\} = \{T_n\} \cup \Lambda$ is a Folner sequence. But I am not sure if assuming that (X, {T_n}) satisfies the $D$-condition, we would obtain that $(X, \{F_n\})$ also satisfies the $D$-condition. I guess not. This is one of the difficulties I came across while trying to prove that $D$-condition implies TMP, which is the direction I think it might be true.